# Opening Multiple Hyperlinks Using Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

So I would like to open a bunch (~25) of hyperlinks from one page.
**Each hyperlink contains the text `Free Win`.**

I simply want each link to open in a new tab in the browser. I've set up my Greasemonkey script like the following, but it only opens the first hyperlink.

```
var TargetLink = $("a:contains('Free Win')")
if (TargetLink.length)
    window.location.href = TargetLink[0].href
```

Comment: That will load current tb with the url...need to use [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) for new tab. Doubt broswer will let you do 25 in short time or people would be messing with user's browser constantly on web sites but I've not tired anything like that for very long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want to open all the links that is having 'Free Win' as text:

```
var TargetLink = $("a:contains('Free Win')")
for (var i =0;i<TargetLink.length;i++)
    window.open(
    TargetLink[i].href,
   '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
 );
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!